# Tapping cell in UICollectionView returns wrong index

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I really don't know what I am missing. I've got a `UICollectionView` set up and the contents are set correctly. The `cellForItemAt` section looks like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DetailsEventImageCell", for: indexPath) as? DetailsEventImageCell
    
    print("Loaded - IndexPathItem: \(indexPath.item)")
    
    cell?.backgroundColor = .clear
    cell?.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    cell?.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell?.eventImage.image = images[indexPath.row]
    
    return cell ?? UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

The `collectionView` shows the cells correctly but here's the problem. When I go into editing Mode and tap through all the cells randomly, sometimes it returns the wrong index and marks the wrong cell (mostly right next to it) as shown in the image below:

[The cell I tap should return indexPath.item = 5 but it does return 4 and marks cell 4 for deletion instead of 5.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBGjb.png)

As the cells are set up correctly I don't know why it occasionally returns the wrong `indexPath` for the selected cell. If I tap on a cell twice it suddenly returns the correct `indexPath`. If I deselect all cells and try again, there some cells return the wrong `indexPath` again.

Here's my `didSelectItemAt` Code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.item)
    if isEditing {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? DetailsEventImageCell {
            cell.isInEditingMode = isEditing
            cell.isSelected = true
        }
    }
}
```

The following two functions might also be the culprit, but I just don't see why it would set up the `collectionView` correctly and then on tapping return the wrong value.

This is my custom cell:

```
class DetailsEventImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var eventImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var selectedForDeletionImage: UIImageView!

var isInEditingMode: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if !isInEditingMode {
            //selectedForDeletionImage.isHidden = true
            isSelected = false
        }
    }
}

override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        if isInEditingMode {
            selectedForDeletionImage.isHidden = isSelected ? false : true
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `setEditing` code

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
        
        collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = editing
        
        //Deselect all selected cells
        if !editing {
            if let indexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
                for indexPath in indexPaths {
                    self.collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false)
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        let indexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems
        for indexPath in indexPaths {
            if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? DetailsEventImageCell {
                cell.isInEditingMode = editing
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying I found out that this seems to be an iOS Simulator related issue. I don't have access to all device sizes, so I sometimes do use it for quick testing.

Tapping cells "slowly" in the simulator does work as expected, but if I tap inside cells too fast it seems like it's not keeping up and selecting the previous cell again.

On an actual device it's possible to tap on cells at any speed and it works as intended.

Edit: The problem seems to only appear on the iOS-Simulator on my Mac Mini late 2012 (macOS Catalina 10.15.6) on XCode 11.7
My Macbook Pro 15" 2019 and all hardware devices I tried (iPhone 11 Pro, ipad Air, iPhone SE 2nd Gen) do work as expected with the same project and the same OS/XCode Build.

Comment: The cells are initialized and reused correctly though. I made debug-prints when the cells are reused and the data is updated. As stated the data is also displayed correctly. When I tap on the cells outside of editing mode they always return the correct indexPath. When I go into Editing-Mode and select mutliple cells in quick succession it returns the wrong indexPath occasionally.

Comment: This also occurs when I only display 5 cells and there's no cells disappearing and reappearing from view to be reused.
The problem still only exists in simulator, on the device it always works as intended and always returns the correct value.

Comment: Well, I'm not dogmatic about that. But I am dogmatic about the notion that directly modifying a cell rather than modifying the source data and flowing that into the interface is wrong. If you can make a very small test project that demonstrates the issue, maybe I could download it (from github for instance) and try it out. You have to understand that I've been making collection views with selected states for _years_ and have never seen this issue; you gotta wonder why that is.

Comment: I know what you mean, maybe my wording was wrong as I'm not a native english speaker. What I'm doing is basically modifying an array of images outside of the collectionView and asigning the right data (the image) to the specific cells when they're loaded/reused. I have added an imageView to the cell to appear when a cell has the state "isSelected" and to not appear when the state of isSelected is false. I am not modifying my source data (images) from within the delegate methods. It's nice that you offer your help, but your answers can come off a little cocky as it's obvious that I am new here.

Comment: I don't doubt that you have way more experience than I do, I am actually programming for iOS for fun, but I've never had this issue on any collectionView or tableView in years (after my initial tries). I tried the code on two iPads and 3 different iPhones and it always returned exactly what I expected it to to the console. The only time it failed was when I tried using the iOS simulator. The Mac Mini I was using is 7 years old now and it's not the fastest anymore so it might actually be responsible for this behaviour.

Comment: I tried running the code on my newer Macbook (2019) in the meantime and it worked as it does on the actual devices. Never ran across a problem like that so I want to apologize for wasting your time. Maybe I should clean up my XCode / reinstall it. Honest thank you for offering your help, matt.

Comment: I can only tell you what I am experiencing. I am not here to troll anyone, I proceeded as I usually do and ran across this strange behaviour. It drove me crazy, that's why I ultimately signed up here. It's strange to see that "tapping cells slowly" works, while tapping them rapidly in succession breaks the functionality. If there was a problem with reusing the cells or assigning the data it shouldn't work when I tap "slowly", too. Having 5 cells on the screen should have them loaded once and not "reused" in any way. And still, in this particular setup it happens.

Comment: Like I say, I've love to see a demo project. Meanwhile you might actually add the info about different Mac models to the answer: that might make it quite useful. Thanks!

Comment: I've added more info to the answer. I will try to reproduce the problem in a new project file and if I can reproduce it I will provide it to you. I've not experienced it before, which is why I came here for help in the first place - never seen something like that before. Obviously I should have tried my hardware devices/other mac-devices before coming here. But I'll take this as a lesson :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the above implementation won't work if u have many cells because cells are reusable.

1. you can collect selected Indexpaths in Array, reload on every didSelece/didDeselect method.
2. Do the UI updates in cellforRowAtItem method.

   ```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {   
       if isEditing {
          self.selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
          self.collectionView.reloadData()
       }
   }
   ```

In didDeselect method will be like...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let index = self.selectedIndexPaths.firstIndex(of: indexPath) {
        self.selectedIndexPaths.remove(at: index)
    }
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

finally cellforRowAtItem will be like...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DetailsEventImageCell", for: indexPath) as? DetailsEventImageCell

print("Loaded - IndexPathItem: \(indexPath.item)")

cell?.backgroundColor = .clear
cell?.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
cell?.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
cell?.eventImage.image = images[indexPath.row]
if self.selectedIndexpaths.contains(indexPath) {
   cell.isSelected = true
} else {
   cell.isSelected = false
}
return cell ?? UICollectionViewCell()
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Serious question: What would be the difference between storing the selected indexPaths inside a var and using collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems? This variable always seems to store the correct indexPaths, even when testing with 100+ cells and selecting all over the place.

Comment: Maybe a problem with OS or Device or performance etc..

Comment: For me it worked on actual hardware devices as I wrote in the answer I've added. Only in simulator the problem seems to occur. My Mac is quite old so it might actually be a performance issue. Someone said "no" though and downvoted me. Really thankful for your help though! Have a nice day